# Windows11 and WSL2: Adjusting Size of Ubuntu Partition yields PositionalParameterNotFound when selecting vdisk

Tags: partitioning, powershell, windows-11, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

**YES**: I have read the docs (see [Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/disk-space#how-to-expand-the-size-of-your-wsl-2-virtual-hard-disk) on increasing WSL2 partition size, and how to [Locate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/disk-space#how-to-locate-the-vhdx-file-and-disk-path-for-your-linux-distribution) partition location).

```
PS C:\Users\user> (Get-ChildItem -Path HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss | Where-Object { $_.GetValue("DistributionName") -eq 'ubuntu' }).GetValue("BasePath") + "\ext4.vhdx"
```

yields

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\ext4.vhdx
```

And then running:

```
PS C:\Users\user> select vdisk file="C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\ext4.vhdx"
```

yields:

```
Select-Object : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument
'file=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\ext4.vhdx'.
At line:1 char:1
+ select vdisk file="C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGro ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Select-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectObjectCommand
```

So what do I do?

Comment: @notthedr01ds  here it is :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it, there's one critical missing piece in the steps that you listed.  Step #3 in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/disk-space#how-to-expand-the-size-of-your-wsl-2-virtual-hard-disk) that you linked is to run:

```
diskpart
```

The `select` command should be entered in the disk partitioning utility.  However, it appears that you are still in PowerShell when you run it.  `select` is *also* a valid PowerShell command (alias, really, for `Select-Object`), but it isn't going to do what you need it to do here, of course.

Running `diskpart` before the `select ...` should at least get you past that error.

Comment: good news sad news. Your command works. Bad news, ubuntu still thinks it only has 250 Gbs... how do I fix this? Why does window's make it so hard to change this

Comment: @SumNeuron Add the output of `lsblk` (from inside WSL) to your question (since we'll need it to be formatted, a comment won't work).  Also, re-run the steps 10-11 in the doc.  What is the output of the commands?  (Also edit this into the question, of course).  Thanks!

Comment: And not sure we can blame Windows here.  The procedure is pretty similar to that of resizing a partition on a physical drive on pure Linux ;-).